# Create service depending on some condition

Tags: angular

I am writing a frontend in Angular Ionic, and would like to have some services depend on the platform.
The service itself, probaly in the constructor, would load methods and properties from an appropriate class for different platforms: mobile web, android, ios. I would like the class to be loaded as a whole, so I do not need to load methods one by one.

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
export DeviceService Implements iDevice{
constructor(){
    if (this.platform.is('ios)) this.device = iosDevice;
}
.
.
.
}
```

and then be able to do `this.device.takePhoto()`, `this.device.pushAlert()`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `userAgent` to achieve that, even if I don't personally like it.
A simple function to detect what type of device is browsing the page could be a function like that:

```
private _getDeviceType() {
  const ua = navigator.userAgent;

  if (/Mobile|iP(hone|od)/.test(ua)) {
    return "iOS";
  } else if (/Android/.test(ua)) {
    return "Android";
  }

  return "desktop or tablet";
};
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not quite what I am asking. I have a way of detecting the platform. My question is how do I populate a services methods at runtime programmatically, preferably not needing to assign method by method.